# "adb shell ls" displays broken folder and file names

Tags: android, linux, shell

"adb shell ls" displays broken folder and file names like below. It seems that the broken strings are prepended at the header and appended in the tail of the names.

What could cause it?

Note that I'm running adb which is installed in embedded Linux.

```
===========below==========
C:\Users\user>adb shell ls
[1;34mbin[0m         [1;34mdev[0m         [1;34mlib[0m         [1;34mmnt
```

...

Comment: Those are teletype/terminal screen codes. Probably color codes. Those are all dirs. Different for a file?

Comment: @Greenapps has right, they are color codes. More exactly, terminal controlling characters to change the _color_ of the file names. Now your terminal doesn't understand them, so it writes them out as if they would be normal characters. You could give a try to another terminal emulator, for example mintty.

Answer (score 0):

Try running
`adb shell command ls`
Read more about `command` [here](http://ss64.com/bash/command.html).
Relevant text from the above link :

> Only shell builtin commands or commands found by searching the PATH are executed. If there is a shell function named ls, running `command ls' within the function will execute the external command ls instead of calling the function recursively.